# Refactoring out common parts of pytest cases

Tags: pytest

I have the following pattern of tests cases

```py
def test_component_feature_1(mock_app):
    # COMMON PART: extract all components widgets from the app and assert their default states
    # Activate component widget 1
    # Assert the response of the remaining components.
    
def test_component_feature_1(mock_app):
    # COMMON PART: extract all components widgets from the app and assert their default 
    # Activate component widget 2
    # Assert the response of the remaining components.
```

How can I refactor out the common part of the test cases?

The obvious solution would be to implement a function to get the component widgets like so

```py
def get_component_widgets(mock_app):
    ...
    return widget1, widget2, ..., widget8
    
def test_component_feature_3(mock_app):
    # Too many component widgets
    widget1, widget2, ..., widget8 = get_component_widgets(mock_app)
    # Activate component widget 3
    # Assert the response of the remaining components.
```

I don't like this approach because my widgets have long, descriptive names.

Is there a built-in way to achieve this?

Comment: I recommend learning and applying `fixtures` -- https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/fixtures.html

Comment: Having each widget as a fixture seems like a logical approach but I assume @Olumide is already aware of them considering their use of `mock_app`.

Answer (score 1):

As @Teejay Bruno suggested in the comments, use [pytest fixtures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/explanation/fixtures.html). Remember that fixtures can [request other fixtures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/how-to/fixtures.html#fixtures-can-request-other-fixtures).

You already used a fixture for `mock_app`. As @tmt suggested, add a fixture for each widget. For example:

```
@pytest.fixture
def mock_app():
    return MyMockApp()

@pytest.fixture
def widget1(mock_app: MyMockApp) -> MyWidget1:
    return mock_app.widget1

@pytest.fixture
def widget2(mock_app: MyMockApp) -> MyWidget2:
    return mock_app.widget2

@pytest.fixture
def widget3(mock_app: MyMockApp, widget1: MyWidget1) -> MyWidget3:
    widget1.do_something()  # in case widget3 depends on widget1
    return mock_app.widget3
```

Now you can assert the defaults, either in a single test:

```
def test_defaults(widget1, widget2, widget3):
    assert widget1.default
    assert widget2.default
    assert widget3.default
```

...or, even better (if applicable), write separate tests so you can immediately tell by pytest's output which widget is misbehaving:

```
def test_widget1_default(widget1):
    assert widget1.default

def test_widget2_default(widget2):
    ...
```

Now when you get to the actual tests, only request the fixtures you need for that test. For example:

```
def test_component_feature_3(mock_app, widget3, widget7, widget8):
    widget3.activate()
    mock_app.do_something()
    assert widget7.something()
    assert widget8.something()
```

Regarding

> my widgets have long, descriptive names

That's a very good idea! If you're having trouble because of long lines, use an auto-formatter like [black](https://github.com/psf/black).

Answer (score 1):

Return some data structure other than a tuple

```
def get_component_widgets(mock_app) -> Dict[widget]:
    ...
    d = dict()
    d["widget1"] = widget1
    ...
    return d
    
def test_component_feature_3(mock_app):
    # Too many component widgets
    d = get_component_widgets(mock_app)
    # Activate component widget 3
    activate(d["widget1"])
    # Assert the response of the remaining components.
```